# Find documents whose analyzed field contains slash and underscore

Tags: elasticsearch

My documents have an analyzed field `url` with content looking like this

```
http://sub.example.com/data/11/222/333/filename.txt
```

I would like to find all documents whose `filename` starts with an underscore. I've tried multiple approaches (wildcard, pattern, query_string, span queries) but I never got the right result. I expect this is because the the underscore is a term separator. How can I write such a query? Is it possible at all without changing the field to not analyzed (which I cannot do at the moment)?

It's ElasticSearch 1.5, but we'll be migrating to at least 2.4 in foreseeable future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to write a `script` that would do that, but it would be amazingly slow.

You best bet (even though you say you can't right now) is changing the field from `analyzed` to a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html).  This way you could have both analyzed and not-analyzed versions to work work.

You could use the [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/docs-reindex.html) to migrate all the data from the old version to the new version (assuming you're using ES 2.3 or greater).